# User.findOne returns null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => 
{
        try
        {
            console.log(req.body.email)
            const user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password})
            if(user)
            {
                return res.redirect("/")
            }
            console.log(user)
            res.status(200).send(user)
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            res.status(400).send(e)
        }
})
```

I am trying to look for a user in MongoDB but the user variable returns `null` and I am getting status code 200 with an empty object.

Thanks for answers. I found the missing point. I stored the hashed password in database but I forget to search for hashed password

Comment: Maybe you didn't use the model correctly, or maybe you didn't put the same data in the database, and it's normal for the status 200 to be restored because you didn't have a condition to check the user value. Please include more code!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should consider not storing passwords as plaintext in your database and when finding a user querying them. I recommend using a hashing algorithm like [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) to validate them.

Regarding your question, you have to know that mongoose **does not** throw an error when it finds no entries and you only send 404 when an error is thrown. I would recommend you changing your code to the following:

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => 
{
        try
        {
            console.log(req.body.email)
            const user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email})

            if (user) {
                // TODO: Use hashing algorithm to verify password
                console.log(user)
                res.status(200).send(user)
                return res.redirect("/")
            } else {
                res.status(400).send("User not found")
            }
            
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            res.status(500).send("Server error: " + e.message)
        }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This didn't match the query. Are you sure the e-mail and password are correct? The syntax is correct. It shows status code of 200, that means your code is perfect, but your email pr password is wrong or there is no data in the database with that email and password. Like @Adwirawien said you should hash your password.

Answer (score 0):

looks like your condition:

```
if(user)
```

should be written

```
if(!user)
```

Or am I wrong ?